# javascript onload slide in

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a childtheme of thematic and I have a couple of div's that I want to slide into the page. It works if I do not include the WordPress jquery file but If I include it this now breaks. I am a bit confused as why?

The script is:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("div.home-sidebar, div.draw-logo")
.css("margin-left",-$(this).width())
.animate({
    marginLeft:0
}, 4000);
$("div.menu-links")
.css("margin-top",-$(this).width())
.animate({
    marginTop:0
}, 5000);
});
```

Comment: By changing the $ to jQuery in my script it worked.

Comment: Wordpress jQuery file uses jQuery.NoConflict() which won't use the $

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use it like this:

```
 (function ($) {
     $(window).load(function () {
         $("div.home-sidebar, div.draw-logo")
             .css("margin-left", -$(this).width())
             .animate({
             marginLeft: 0
         }, 4000);
         $("div.menu-links")
             .css("margin-top", -$(this).width())
             .animate({
             marginTop: 0
         }, 5000);
     });
 })(jQuery);
```

Because `jQuery` is used by wordpress and if you want to refer it to with `$` then you can use this `iife` to pass `jQuery` and use `$` in place of it.